# Is the execution of java code without source file possible?

Tags: java, drm

I'm currently working on a simple Java project where I wanted to test if DRM in java is possible.
I had different thoughts about an approach to this topic.

My last idea was about running java code without having the source or any physical copy of the program on my machine. So, for example, I have a Program on my machine that kind of downloads the compiled classes into memory and then runs it from there. 
I know that this is possible in other languages.

My problem is that I don't know if this is possible at all and if so what I have to search for? I already googled my question in several ways but not received an answer that was helpful.

Maybe you can tell me if the way would work at all and what I have to search for then.

If you have another approach for DRM in Java I would be grateful if you let me know.

Comment: all you need to execute code written in Java, is the compiled java class. So, yes. You don't need the original source code to run it

Comment: after you compile the source it turn into class files, these class files are what your JVM executes , so you need just the class files not the source.

Comment: Ok, I see I have to edit my question. The main goal is to run the program without having the program file or the source file physically on my computer. I want to load it from a server into the memory of the pc and run it from there. With that measure, I want to prevent access to my code in any way.

Comment: You can execute Java byte code, I.e. classes, without storing them on the disk. But, they still have to be stored in RAM (memory). So, it is not possible to execute code that is not physically stored at all on your computer. While you can't read the memory of a running program directly, an attacker could still obtain the code from RAM by using a debugger. The only way to completely prevent access to the code is by running it on a different, secured computer controlled only by you - e.g. on a web server, by implementing your app as a web app.

Comment: This has been done and countered. There are java decompilers that can take a class file and reconstruct the source. All the comments and original source is gone, but the code can be reconstructed. Why do you wish to conceal your source?

Comment: ok, can you tell me where I can find more information about executing Java in Memory without storing it on the disk? I would be very grateful.

Comment: I like to conceal my source because I'm planning some further projects where it could be helpful to do so. So that nobody can steal my idea.